# How to select an item from GridView by long pressing ,on so i need to open the Contextual ActionBar menu with Item Selected?

Tags: android, gridview

I designed a view pager with grid view containing list of Icon's .I need to show contextual action bar by selecting an Icon and also i need to select that icon too.Kindly asking you to give me a suggestion?

Am also using the function `OnItemLongClickListener()`.Help me out to do the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
mMultiChoiceModeListener = new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mode = null;
            mAdapter.clearSelection();
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Options");
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode, menu); // inflate your menu for the contextual action bar here
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // handle the click of the buttons of the contextual action bar here as a normal menu
            }
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        }
    };
    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            mGrid.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            arg1.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
    mGrid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(mMultiChoiceModeListener);
```

And use a normal menu to this!
I see a bug here, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Change this

```
        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            mGrid.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            arg1.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

to this:

```
        mGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            arg1.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And on the on create put this:

```
mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```